# Regex not matching properly in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have written a program to find all the links in an HTML page:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String base = "http://www.oracle.com/";
    URL url = new URL(base);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String inputLine = null;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuffer = stringBuffer.append(inputLine).append("\n");
    }

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("<a .*href=\"([^\"]+)\".*</a>", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(stringBuffer.toString());

    ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()){
        String relUrl = matcher.group(1);
        String fullUrl = relUrl.startsWith("/")?base+relUrl.substring(1):relUrl;
        urlList.add(fullUrl);
        System.out.println(fullUrl);
    }

    in.close();
}
```

For some reason, when I run this code it is only matching one link. However, when I run it without the `DOTALL` flag, it matches 108 links. The reason I included the `DOTALL` flag is to match links where the `a` tag may go over one line, such as:

```
    <li><a data-lbl="solutions" href="https://www.oracle.com/solutions/index.html#menu-solutions" data-trackas="hnav" class="u01nav">
<h3>Solutions</h3>
</a></li>
```

According to [here](https://regex101.com/), the regex `<a .*href=\"([^\"]+)\".*<\/a>` matches the HTML above. (this is slightly different than the one I used in the code because Eclipse wouldn't let me escape the `/` character)

Comment: Regex is not supposed to be used for non-regularly structured input. This is what parsers, such as an HTML Parser, are for.

Comment: I understand, but an HTML Parser is not an option for me (it is a challenge assignment for a course, where we are asked to use regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your regex is greedy `.*` in your regex matches all the characters. So make it non-greedy `.*?` ..

```
"<a .*?href=\"([^\"]+)\".*?</a>"
```

or

```
"<a [^<>]*\\bhref=\"([^\"]+)\".*?</a>"
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Just out of curiosity, why is it that without the `DOTALL` flag, the pattern is able to match 100 or so links? I thought the `DOTALL` flag didn't affect the greediness of the pattern?

Comment: because there are 100 anchor tags exists on a single line.

Comment: Yes, but why for those 100 tags, did the `.*` not match all the characters?

Comment: may be bacause of \n char exists in between. I'm still not clear about what you mean. Post an example data and the regex you tried on regex101. Then give me the link back.

Comment: @SimonZhu `DOTALL` does not affect greediness, but what it actually does is it allows the dot in `.*` to match newlines. Thus, `.*` will consume the whole page until the last occurrence of `href=...`